# Jupyter was installed with conda, It worked but now no longer works - nor do fresh installations

Tags: numpy, anaconda, jupyter

I installed Jupyter on my OSX 10.10 using conda. It worked. Then I tried to install scikit-learn. I was asked if I wanted to update ipython etc. and agreed. Jupyter no longer works.

I have tried installing Python 3.5(and separately 3.4) into a fresh environment and activating it, together with Jupyter,numpy,scipy,pandas,and scikit-learn all at the same time to allow for dependencies. No joy.

So I just tried python3.4 and Jupyter in a fresh environment. Still no joy, though python does work through the terminal.

I get the error message shown below: Any help would be really appreciated.

```
ImportError: bad magic number in 'code': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
[E 15:03:18.772 NotebookApp] {
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6",
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch"
    }
```